# Timeout issue in Netbeans while deploying JBoss Server - Not Resolved

Tags: java, netbeans, jboss, netbeans-8

At times, I get the following error while deploying the code through Netbeans.
Not sure why this is happening. Tried increasing  time to 15000 in ***standalone.xml***. Still facing this error.

Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'deploy' at address '[("deployment" => "server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")]'

***Deploy of deployment "server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: "JBAS013487: Operation timed out awaiting service container stability"***

***ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS013413: Timeout after [5000] seconds waiting for service container stability while finalizing an operation.***

***Process must be restarted. Step that first updated the service container was 'deploy' at address '[("deployment" => "server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")]'***

Comment: the issue is in your war file, try to start your server manually and look at the service container via the jboss-cli

Comment: How to start manually? @ehsavoie

Comment: ./standalone.sh and copy current logs